# MP3 playback and stop issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mp3, avaudioplayer, playback

This code works fine until I exit the view and try to come back into it.  If I do this, the stop button no longer works.  How do I get it to still work after leaving the view?

```
-(IBAction)musiconButtonClicked:(id)sender{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NextRevIt" ofType:@"mp3"];
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [audioPlayer play];


}

-(IBAction)musicoffButtonClicked:(id)sender{

    [audioPlayer stop];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to release the audio player when you are done with it.

You should also use `[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];` before `play` in your code.